# How to make Flash files

Tags: flash, adobe

I have **Adobe Master Collection 5.5**.  I am not much of a fan of Flash, however I have a project that requires me to build a Flash object/file

All the flash object needs to do is
- Show a background image for 5 seconds
- After 5 seconds to a different background image and show a Button on it
- If the Button is clicked, it will copy some pre-defined text to the users clipboard and change the background image once again and hide the Button.

Here is what I have...

**Adobe Flash Builder 4.5**   - 1GB

**Adobe Flash Pro CS5.5**  - 714MB

**Adobe Flash Catalyst CS5.5**  - 899MB

I am not sure what the difference is.

Based off the project I described above, which program should I install to build it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Adobe:

Flash Professional, design based authoring tool

> Adobe® Flash® Professional CS5.5 software is the industry-leading
>   authoring environment for producing expressive interactive content.
>   Create immersive experiences that present consistently to audiences
>   across desktops, smartphones, tablets, and televisions.

Flash Builder, programmatic code with declarative MXML markup

> Adobe® Flash® Builder® 4.5 Premium software is an Eclipse™ based
>   development tool for rapidly building expressive mobile, web, and
>   desktop applications using ActionScript® and the open source Flex
>   framework. Use professional testing tools to build higher performing
>   applications.

Flash Catalyst, interactive design

> Adobe® Flash® Catalyst® CS5.5 is approachable interaction design
>   software that enables you to easily transform Adobe Photoshop®,
>   Illustrator®, and Fireworks® artwork into expressive, fully
>   interactive projects without writing code, and leverage the reach and
>   consistency of the Adobe Flash Platform.

Based upon your needs Flash Pro could easily import a few images to the library, and provide basic code editing needed to quickly complete your task.

Comment: thanks, it is a bit confusing, as I would of thought actionscript might of been needed

Comment: That's understandable, as parity within the Flash product line certainly can be confusing at first glance.  Flash Pro has a built-in code editor for ActionScript - actions can be incorporated in the timeline or linked to symbols.  Flash Builder is Eclipse, but you could embed visual assets via ActionScript.  You'll likely need code to handle a MouseEvent.CLICK event for what you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flash Pro to publish/compile an SWF.